# self-serve data capability stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, presto

what are folks using to provide a self-serve, scalable data capability?

Constraints are: the system must run on AWS and not use EMR (or hadoop/hdfs at all, so no cloudera either)

To be clear, requirements are:

1. upload one or more files from desktop (can be a UI or API call) to S3, and decide whether to make it a private file (only visible to the user who uploaded it) or share with specific users
2. ability to SQL query those files including joins between files that other users uploaded+shared
3. run python, R, java, scala code at scale (not single node) using EC2 cluster without sshing into the ec2. bonus points for ability to schedule these workflows on regular basis

Comment: Do you want to use self managed Presto? How big your data/files are? How many users will be using this solution?

Comment: 50 users, we alreeady have self-manageed Preesto. Total data is 500GB, nwe data might be 2GB sizze per file

Comment: Seems like you are looking for an orchestration layer on top of your Presto cluster to handle these use cases. Did you evaluate Qubole? That will give you flexibility to upload files, create tables on those s3 files, run Presto queries, workload aware autoscaling, spot support with fault tolerance, No HDFS dependency etc. Should be cost effective as well because you don't need to keep all the ec2 machines up all the time.